# MySQL subqueries weird behavior

Tags: mysql, subquery

I was making a query for search but the result should be obtained from three tables and it works fine for only two characters after that it returns empty rows so can anyone help please 
here is my query

```
SELECT * 
FROM tables
WHERE table2_id
IN (

SELECT id
FROM table2
WHERE table3_id
IN (

SELECT id
FROM table3
WHERE name LIKE  '%in%'
)
OR
)
name LIKE 'in%' 
AND id <>  '8'
```

Any suggestions if I am making the right things and what went wrong when its more than two characters

Comment: What does your table structure look like?

Comment: sample data would be helpful. I guess it has something to do with your `LIKE` expression `%in%` -> returnin everything that **contains in** and in% -> returns everything that **starts with in**

Comment: all ids are integers and the names text mysql driver MyIssam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a completely ridiculous query! Use a join - that's what it's for!

```
SELECT tables.*
FROM tables JOIN table2 ON tables.table2_id = table2.id
     JOIN table3 ON table2.table3_id = table3.id
WHERE (name LIKE  '%in%' OR name LIKE 'in%' AND id <> 8
```

Comment: Thank you very much I want to tell you two things
1- The query you wrote is completely wrong 
2- You should not say ridiculous 
And the thing that is required from the query is to search in two tables and then return the value from the other 
Thanks for you help I really Appreciate it ;)

Comment: @UserB At the very minimum table2 and table3 can be joined in a query. I assumed that table2.id is unique - if so my query is the same as yours. If it's not unique you could get duplicates - but you did say it's an id and id's should be unique. One other edit `SELECT tables.*` instead of just `*` - to return results only from the main table.

Comment: In fact you are right the id is unique
But I solved it without table3 
Thanks